# Production build tries to load app-extjs?_dc=20220503223151. The file that doesn't exist

Tags: extjs

Using ExtJS 7.3.1.27

Any idea why ExtJS tries to load that non-existing path?

The URL is:

```
app-extjs?_dc=20220503223151
```

where "app" is the name of the application.

app.json:

```
{
    "name": "App",

    "namespace": "App",
    "version": "1.1.0.0",
    "framework": "ext",
    "template": "universalclassicmodern",
    "env": "${build.environment}",
    "indexHtmlPath": "index.html",
    "locale": "es",
    "requires": [
        "font-awesome",
        "ext-ux",
        "ext-locale"
    ],
    "builds": {
        "desktop": {
            "toolkit": "classic",
            "theme": "Andromeda",
            "sass": {
                "generated": {
                    "var": "${build.id}/sass/save.scss",
                    "src": "${build.id}/sass/save"
                }
            }
        },
        "phone": {
            "toolkit": "modern",
            "theme": "theme-material",
            "sass": {
                "generated": {
                    "var": "${build.id}/sass/save.scss",
                    "src": "${build.id}/sass/save"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "classpath": [
        "app/shared/src",
        "app/${build.id}/src"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        "app/shared/overrides",
        "app/${build.id}/overrides"
    ],
    "sass": {
        "namespace": "App",
        "etc": [
            "sass/etc/all.scss"
        ],
        "var": [
            "app/shared/sass/var.scss",
            "app/${build.id}/sass/var.scss"
        ],
        "src": [
            "app/shared/src/sass/src.scss",
            "app/${build.id}/sass/src.scss"
        ]
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "path": "resources",
            "output": "shared"
        },
        {
            "path": "resources/${build.id}"
        }
    ],
    "output": {
        "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
        "page": "index.html",
        "manifest": "generatedFiles/${build.id}.json",
        "js": "generatedFiles/${build.id}/app.js",
        "appCache": {
            "enable": false
        },
        "resources": {
            "path": "${build.id}/resources",
            "shared": "resources"
        }
    },
    "fashion": {
        "missingParameters": "error",
        "inliner": {
            "enable": false
        }
    },
    "js": [

    ],
    "css": [
        {
            "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
            "bundle": true,
            "exclude": [
                "fashion"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "loader": {
        "cache": false,
        "cacheParam": "_dc"
    },
    "production": {
        "js": [
            {
                "path": "app.js",
                "bundle": true
            },
            {
                "path": "${app.webpack.bundle}",
                "compress": false
            },
            {
                "path": "jsencrypt.min.js",
                "bundle": false
            }
        ],
        "output": {
            "appCache": {
                "enable": false,
                "path": "cache.appcache"
            }
        },
        "loader": {
            "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
        },
        "cache": {
            "enable": true
        },
        "compressor": {
            "type": "yui"
        }
    },
    "testing": {
        "js": [
            {
                "path": "app.js",
                "bundle": true
            },
            {
                "path": "${app.webpack.bundle}",
                "compress": false
            },
            {
                "path": "jsencrypt.min.js",
                "bundle": false
            }
        ],
        "output": {
            "appCache": {
                "enable": false,
                "path": "cache.appcache"
            }
        },
        "loader": {
            "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
        },
        "cache": {
            "enable": true
        },
        "compressor": {
            "type": "yui"
        }
    },
    "development": {
        "js": [
            {
                "path": "app.js",
                "bundle": true
            },
            {
                "path": "main.js"
            },
            {
                "path": "node_modules/faker/dist/faker.min.js",
                "bundle": true
            },
            {
                "path": "node_modules/jsencrypt/bin/jsencrypt.min.js",
                "bundle": true
            }
        ],
        "watch": {
            "delay": 250
        }
    },
    "bootstrap": {
        "base": "${app.dir}",
        "manifest": "generatedFiles/${build.id}.json",
        "microloader": "generatedFiles/bootstrap.js",
        "css": "generatedFiles/bootstrap.css"
    },
    "cache": {
        "enable": false,
        "deltas": "${build.id}/deltas"
    },
    "appCache": {
        "cache": [
            "index.html"
        ],
        "network": [
            "*"
        ],
        "fallback": []
    },
    "archivePath": "archive/${build.id}",
    "ignore": [
        "(^|/)CVS(/?$|/.*?$)"
    ],
    "id": "60bcc415-f5ee-4ebd-a3f5-6aba304f704b",
    "slicer": null
}

Thanks.
```

Comment: You would have to post the app.json at least.

Comment: app.json included. Thanks.

Comment: What is `app.webpack.bundle` set to? This might be the problem